# Anyway to use dbutils.fs commands inside a foreachpartition?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to move files within adls gen2, the standard dbtutils.fs.mv is pretty slow for the task as the filecount exceeds well beyond 200k. I was thinking to parallelize the process so I created an RDD out of the filelist and tried using foreachPartition and within that dbutils.fs.mv. When I try to do it, it throws the error - java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs

Also tried using `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.wasbs.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")` but this just gives another error on the lines of Azure Native File system.

Any other method to achieve this is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share the complete stack trace of the error message which you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with foreachPartition, but with using ADLS Gen2, it worked fine on mounted storage.